# Delete error in CRUD RESTful API(Node.js , Express, Mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, crud

I am using mongoose in this example. While trying to delete ,the following error is being shown to me
`Cannot DELETE /5e69e2fde0fa464ee01dd68d`

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going wrong .I am a complete beginner in Node.js , MongoDB and creating RESTful APIs
The code given below is the function I am using to delete .

```
router.delete('/:id', getSubscriber, async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await res.subscriber.remove()
      res.json({ message: 'Deleted Subscriber' })
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
    }
  })
```

and here is the getSubscriber function

```
async function getSubscriber(req, res, next) {
  let subscriber
  try {
    subscriber = await Subscriber.findById(req.params.id)
    if (subscriber == null) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Cannot find subscriber' })
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }

  res.subscriber = subscriber
  next()
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you share your code where this `router` is. used?  Seems as if the api path is not valid.

Comment: `DELETE http://localhost:3000/5e69e2fde0fa464ee01dd68d` I assume this code is correct as the remaining functions with same parameters are working flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

```
router.delete('/:id', getSubscriber, async (req, res) => {
try {

   //Here try creating an instance of your model.
   //I think your schema is named subscriber so
   const deleteSuscriber = await Suscriber.remove({_id:req.params.id});
   res.json(deleteSuscriber);

} catch (err) {
  res.status(500).json({ message: err})
}
});
```

Here express will put the variable in *req.params* form the incoming request.
Hope this works!!
[Here you can find the documentation on making CRUD Rest API](https://kedarsedai.github.io/blog/)

Comment: Alright , so I tried just changing the delete function ,however it didn't work. However, since I hadn't done much work I started from scratch ,using your blog post which you linked and it worked like a charm .Thanks.